# Cython sizeof incomplete type

Tags: c, enums, cython

I am trying to compile a library named PyFMI, however it fails due to some errors about sizeof incomplete types.

My question is whether or not someone can help me understand why this happens. Because the file with the incomplete type is a c file generated by Cython. It is therefore somewhat mysterious to me how Cython does not generate any error messages, but produces incorrect C code.

The error message I receive is:

> error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘enum fmi1_status_kind_t’
>            return _PyLong_FromByteArray(bytes, sizeof(enum fmi1_status_kind_t),

I also get the following warning which may be relevant:

> warning: ‘enum fmi1_status_kind_t’ declared inside parameter list
>    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__fmi1_status_kind_t(enum fmi1_status_kind_t value);

What puzzles me is that the definition of the enum looks similar to other enums who don't generate any error messages:

```
    cdef enum fmi1_status_kind_t:
    fmi1_do_step_status = 0
    fmi1_pending_status = 1
    fmi1_last_successful_time = 2
```

These definitions are in a pxd file which is imported by most of the files in the code.

Does anyone have any ideas why Cython produces incomplete types, such as in my case?

Comment: Can you see the enum definition anywhere in the generated C code?

Comment: I cannot tell why this happens but it's been fixed by changing the enum to a ctypedef in the pxd file.